# Regex for removing tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this tag:

```
const tag = '<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28.3 28.3" id="logo-square-empty"><path fill="none" d="M-.7-.9h30v30h-30z" /><path d="M0 28.3h28.3V0H0v28.3zM3.5 3.5h21.3v21.3H3.5V3.5z" /></symbol>'
```

I want to remove the `<symbol>` and `</symbol>` tags, and get this result:

```
<path fill="none" d="M-.7-.9h30v30h-30z" /><path d="M0 28.3h28.3V0H0v28.3zM3.5 3.5h21.3v21.3H3.5V3.5z" />
```

So I wrote this regex:

```
/</?symbol[^>]*>/;
```

Which can be tested here: https://regexr.com/42fan

And I should be able to do:

```
const regex = /</?symbol[^>]*>/;
const replacedString = tag.replace(regex, '');
```

But I get `Parsing error: Unexpected token ^`. How should I write it to avoid this parsing error?

Comment: [You should not try to parse HTML with a regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6320039)

Comment: Use `/<?symbol[^>]*>/;` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with the following regex :

```
const regex = /<\/?symbol[^>]*>/;
const replacedString = tag.replace(regex, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing HTML we can manipulate with `tag` as HTML:

```js
const tag = '<symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28.3 28.3" id="logo-square-empty"><path fill="none" d="M-.7-.9h30v30h-30z" /><path d="M0 28.3h28.3V0H0v28.3zM3.5 3.5h21.3v21.3H3.5V3.5z" /></symbol>'

var div = document.createElement('DIV')
div.innerHTML = tag
result = div.firstElementChild.innerHTML.toString()
console.log(result)
```

Comment: You are assuming that you are in the client

Answer (score 0):

You have not escaped the `/` in your regular expression. You won't have errors with this:

```
/<\/?symbol[^>]*>/
```

That said, it won't work for your task and is still a bad idea to parse your HTML with a regex. And you may prefer to work directly with your DOM, using a `getElementByXXX` javascript method.